# mysql_fetch_array returns nothing while mysql_num_rows returns 4 in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code in php that accesses a mysql database in sorted order, then prints out the info in a table. However, whenever it calls mysql_fetch_array, the function returns nothing, even though mysql_num_rows is 4. That is, if I do $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);, $row['name'] is "" even though there is most certainly a name column in the table. A snippet of the code is below:

```
<?php
include_once("include.php");
$number=0;
if(!isset($_GET['scores'])) {
   $number=10;
}
else if((int )$_GET['scores']>100) {
   $number=100;
}
else if((int) $_GET['scores']<0) {
   $number=10;
}
else {
   $number=(int) $_GET['scores'];
}

$con=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$dbtable_scores." ORDER BY score DESC,date;", $con);
$num=1;
echo("<table>");
echo("<tr><td>position</td><td>Name</td><td>score</td><td>date</td></tr>");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result) && $num<=$number) {
   echo("<tr>");
   echo("<td>".$num."</td>");
   echo("<td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['score']."</td><td>".$row['date']."</td>");
   echo("</tr>");
   $num++;
}
echo("</table>");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I have checked the query in mysql cli, and it seems to work fine. However, as you will see if you go to http://mtgames.org/index.php, the table has only the numbers that are not generated from mysql. The mysql table has columns name, score, date, among others.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
-Michael.

Comment: could you format your code , please? Select your code and press `{}` button to do so.

Comment: `&& $num<=$number` why do you need this part?

Comment: can you do a var_dump($row) after the start of the while loop, and show us the output.

Answer (score 3):

`$row` is not being set to the result of `mysql_fetch_array()`, it's being set to `mysql_fetch_array() && $num <= $number`, which is probably equal to `true`.  It might work if you put some parentheses around `($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` but you could save yourself some heartache by moving the && to an if statement that wraps the contents of the while.

A look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php confirms this.  `&&` has higher operator precedence than assignment, `=`.  However, `and` has lower precedence.  I never knew that!  Why, oh why, php?

Comment: Yep, that works -- ignore my previous comment on the other post, my screen reader went to the wrong edit field :).

Answer (score 1):

maybe try `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` opposed to `mysql_fetch_array($result)`?